# get weird cursor position

Tags: c++, visual-c++, winapi, gdi+

Ok so I'm working with vectors today yaya!
well im also working with `getcursorpos()` and i get weird results.
here is the code:

```
VOID fRegularShot(HDC hdc, HWND hWnd)
{
    Graphics graphics(hdc);
    Image shot(L"RegularShots.png");
    long index=0;
    while(index<=(long)pRegularShots.size())
    {
        index+=2;
        int x=pRegularShots.at(index);
        int y1=index+1;
        int y=pRegularShots.at(y1);
        graphics.DrawImage(&shot, x, y);
    }
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
event
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    iRegularShots=0;
    POINT pt;
    GetCursorPos(&pt);
    pRegularShots.insert(pRegularShots.begin()+1, pt.y);
    pRegularShots.insert(pRegularShots.begin()+1, pt.x);
    InvalidateRect(hWnd, rect, false);
    break;
```

Well basically function `fregularshots()` get called and use the vector elements which contains the positions of the cursor than draws the image on the cursor positions.
but it doesn't seem to draw it on the cursor positions.
any ideas?

Comment: Please use double spaces to breakline instead of the <br> tag.
Also please use the code button instead of <pre> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetCursorPos returns cursor position in screen coordinates. Use ScreenToClient(hWnd, ...) to convert it to window client coordinates.

```
GetCursorPos(&pt);
ScreenToClient(hWnd, &pt);
```

You can work also without GetCursorPos function. When WM_LBUTTONDOWN notification is received, lParam contains window client mouse coordinates: x in low-order word, y in high-order word:

```
xPos = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam); 
yPos = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam);
```

Edit:
Let's make this code more simple.

```
vector<POINT> pRegularShots;

VOID fRegularShot(HDC hdc, HWND hWnd) 
{ 
    Graphics graphics(hdc); 
    Image shot(L"RegularShots.png"); 
    long index=0; 
    while(index < (long)pRegularShots.size()) 
    { 
        graphics.DrawImage(&shot, pRegularShots[index].x, pRegularShots[index].y); 
        ++index;
    } 
} 


case WM_LBUTTONDOWN: 
    POINT pt; 
    pt.x = GET_X_LPARAM(lParam); 
    pt.y = GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam); 
    pRegularShots.push_back(pt); 
    InvalidateRect(hWnd, rect, false); 
    break;
```

Comment: Didn't work - what do you mean? Did something changed? Give more information. For example, click in the left window corner, x and y int WM_LBUTTONDOWN should be some small values. What values do you have in fRegularShot? Where image is drawn? Also, to make the program logic clear, use vector<POINT> instead of vector<int>. You have some problems with vectot indexes.

Comment: ok well it compiles, but nothing changes still gives wrong coordinates. that what it should do, cursor x = 150 and y = 20. than image will be drawen and its position is x = 150 and y = 20 but im getting wrong coordiantes

Comment: @Ramiz Toma: Do you mean the coordinates are flipped (x=20, y=150) or completely wrong? If you haven't done it yet, I think you should take Alex advice on changing the vector from `vector<int>` to `vector<PointF>` (PointF is defined in GDI+) If you have an IDE that can debug, could you put a breakpoint in when you draw it and check the values in your vector?

Comment: ok i couldn't go with your idea or his bout <po>........... but i went with your idea with using breakpoint... on the first left mouse button is down i get x= something and y=0 totally not true.....

Comment: I just read your conversation (`"they didn't work"`) in these comments and wondered whether I accidentally opened the browser tab for our internal customer support system. :-)

Comment: @Ramiz Toma: right so now debug your program and check (put a breakpoint) when you add the values to the vector. Do you add the corect values to the vector?